# Mutation wait for array to be filled with big json files, vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

So I have a for loop that loads MANY urls that would fill up my array. How can we tell if the array is done loading the payload?

```
  console.log(state.getOrdersIDFromJsonGetOrdersAPI.length);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(state.getOrdersIDFromJsonGetOrdersAPI.length);
  }, 1000);
```

This outputs

0

500

I'm super new to vuex and synchronous and asynchronous function, seems like it doesn't wait for the for loop to finish before executing the next code. Making my function synchronous would make the function finish in 20 seconds rather than 2 seconds with asynchronous. Anyway, here's my whole function if it's needed. Thank you SO MUCH in advance.

```
  mutations: {
    // START OF GET ORDERS
    getAPIMutation(state) {
      var Timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime());
      var startdate = moment()
        .startOf("month")
        .format();
      var enddate = moment()
        .endOf("month")
        .format();
      for (let offset = 0; offset != 5000; offset = offset + 100) {
        const HashGetOrders = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
          "/orders/get" +
            "access_token" +
            "50000501d32u2qYccRgmttfnmtpwHtzEj0jsrCOvVTpt114ed4134xBPi2cuEPiw" +
            "app_key" +
            "123335" +
            "created_after" +
            startdate +
            "created_before" +
            enddate +
            "offset" +
            offset +
            "sign_method" +
            "sha256" +
            "timestamp" +
            Timestamp,
          secret_key
        );
        const SignGetOrders = HashGetOrders.toString().toUpperCase();
        const UrlGetOrder = encodeUrl(
          "https://api.lazada.com.ph/rest/orders/get?" +
            "offset=" +
            offset +
            "&created_before=" +
            encodeURIComponent(enddate) +
            "&created_after=" +
            encodeURIComponent(startdate) +
            "&app_key=" +
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" +
            "&sign_method=" +
            "sha256" +
            "&timestamp=" +
            Timestamp +
            "&access_token=" +
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" +
            "&sign=" +
            SignGetOrders
        );
        const HashGetProducts = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
          "/products/get" +
            "access_token50000501809wqvratQFYd1bef630aasBtR2dJgQl2hRwCE1FOSeQxxwMthxJ9Iic" +
            "app_key123335" +
            "filterall" +
            "offset" +
            offset +
            "sign_methodsha256" +
            "timestamp" +
            Timestamp,
          secret_key
        );
        const SignFirst = HashGetProducts.toString().toUpperCase();
        const UrlGetProducts = encodeUrl(
          "https://api.lazada.com.ph/rest/products/get?" +
            "filter=all" +
            "&offset=" +
            offset +
            "&app_key=xxxxx" +
            "&sign_method=sha256" +
            "&timestamp=" +
            Timestamp +
            "&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxx" +
            "&sign=" +
            SignFirst
        );
        axios.get(UrlGetProducts).then((response) => {
          let getJsonAPI = response.data.data.products;
          if (
            response &&
            response.data &&
            response.data.data &&
            response.data.data.products &&
            response.data.data.products.length > 0
          ) {
            state.jsonGetProductsAPI.push(getJsonAPI);
          }
        });

        axios.get(UrlGetOrder).then((response) => {
          let getJsonAPI = response.data.data.orders;
          if (response.data.data.count > 0) {
            getJsonAPI.forEach((order) => {
              state.jsonGetOrdersAPI.push({
                order_id: order.order_id,
                status: order.statuses[0],
                price:
                  parseFloat(order.price.replace(",", "")) +
                  parseFloat(order.shipping_fee) +
                  parseFloat(order.voucher),
              });
              state.getOrdersIDFromJsonGetOrdersAPI.push(order.order_id);
            });
          }
        });
      }
      console.log(state.getOrdersIDFromJsonGetOrdersAPI.length);
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(state.getOrdersIDFromJsonGetOrdersAPI.length);
      }, 1000);
    },
  },
```

Comment: Hard to say what is going on with your api calls, but one important thing: All your asyncronous code should accure in actions, when payload is ready you should call a mutation yo store the result.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Comment: As @DavidGo said, mutations must be pure and simple functions. Move your logic into 'actions' then commit changes in proper time.